# Can I configure Play/Pause button to work systemwide, regardless of the app playing the music?

Tags: sound, shortcut-keys, media, audio-player

Using HP pavilion laptop, and there's a Play/Pause button on the keyboard, I want to work and pause/play the app that is currently playing music.

I had windows before, and it worked just fine. Right now, Ubuntu is the only OS running.

I get this when I press this button:
[A sign of no entrance at the bottom of the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gdmBQ.png)

Using Ubuntu 23.04 x86_64.

What I tried doing:
`settings>keyboard>shortcuts>sound and media>` and then putting the key for `Play(or play/pause)`, but it didn't work (putting any other key combination didn't work too).

Running `playerctl play-pause` but got `No players found` as a response.

I want something to work systemwide, and not a setting of an application. So if I have YouTube in my browser, or video on VLC, or a third party app for music, it'll work regardless. Is there such a thing?